# Merge 2 YAML files with update in-place only

Tags: json, yaml, jq, yq

I have a need to merge two YAML files with YQ/JQ update only on the map file. Let me explain my scenario.

`data.yaml`

```yaml
data1:
  subkey1: subvalue1
  subkey2: subvalue2

data2: value2

data3:
  subkey3: subvalue3
```

`map.yaml`

```yaml
data1:

data3:
  subkey3:
```

**Expected outcome:**

```yaml
data1:
  subkey1: subvalue1
  subkey2: subvalue2

data3:
  subkey3: subvalue3
```

I tried to look up and couldn't find any solution to achieve this. The data & map are supposed to be changing.  Is there any way to achieve this in jq or yq?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "merge" here.  Also, would you accept a solution using gojq (the Go implementation of jq)?

Comment: @peak jq using Go is fine as well. Merge may not be the right word. What I want to do is - keep data in a YAML file and extract only necessary data out using a mapping file.

Comment: @peak It's the opposite of a merge (union); it's the extraction of a subset of the structure (intersection).

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired output and might be close to what you want:

```
gojq -n --yaml-input --yaml-output '
  input as $data
  | input as $map
  | reduce ($map | keys[]) as $k ({}; .[$k] = $data[$k])
' data.yaml map.yaml
```

Then again, maybe this is even closer:

```
gojq -n --yaml-input --yaml-output '
  input as $data
  | input as $map
  | reduce ($map | tostream | select(length==2)) as [$k, $_] ({}; setpath($k; $data | getpath($k)) )
' data.yaml map.yaml
```